# sql datatype real create issue of getting proper value actual value 1.30 but what i got is 1.3

Tags: sql

in database i have datatype real 
when i try to insert value like 1.30 it insert as 1.3
i make code below is code 
@abc working fine
but @abcd due to real datatype its not working

```
declare @minutes as int 
set @minutes = 250
declare @abc as nvarchar(10)
declare @abcd as real
Set @abcd = Cast(rtrim(isnull(cast(nullif((@minutes / 60) , 0 ) as varchar ) + '.' ,'' ) + isnull(CAST(nullif((@minutes % 60) ,0 ) AS VARCHAR(2) ) + '' ,'' ) ) as numeric(36,2)) 
Set @abc = Cast(rtrim(isnull(cast(nullif((@minutes / 60) , 0 ) as varchar ) + '.' ,'' ) + isnull(CAST(nullif((@minutes % 60) ,0 ) AS VARCHAR(2) ) + '' ,'' ) ) as numeric(36,2)) 
print @abcd
print @abc


4.1
4.10
```

Comment: As numbers 1.3 and 1.30 are identical. No difference what so ever. If you try to store a time as `HOURS.MINUTES` then you should use a string type instead of a number type. Notice that 90 minutes should become `1.30` and 63 minutes should become `1.03`. Or store it as two values.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what the issue is.  `real` is an internal data type that supports many decimal places.

If you want a fixed number of decimal places, then you want a `numeric`/`decimal`.  Something like:

```
declare @abcd numeric(10, 2);
```

This has two decimal place sand you should not get results to one decimal places.

Comment: what i got result with real type is 1.3 but what i want is 1.30

Comment: thanks for reply but within real datatype i want value as 1.30

Comment: @jimmydarji Then make the obvious adjustment to the precision specifier.